# FLATTEN On bag NOT working as expected

Tags: apache-pig, flatten, bag

**Input :** a.csv file having a Map data

```
[banks#{(bofa),(chase)}]
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'a.csv' AS (bank_details:map[]);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(bank_details#'banks') AS bank_name;
```

**Output : B :**

```
({(bofa),(chase)})
```

Applying Flatten on bag

```
C = FOREACH A GENERATE bank_details#'banks' AS banks: bag{t:(bank:chararray)};
D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN(banks);
```

**Output : D :**

```
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing [POProject (Name: Project[bag][0] - scope-114 Operator Key: scope-114) children: null at []]: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.DataBag
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:366)
```

**Expected Output :**

```
(bofa)
(chase)
```

If input file has got a bag as below :

**Input : a.csv**

```
{(bofa),(chase)}
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'a.csv' AS (bank_details:bag{t:(bank_name:chararray)});
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(bank_details) AS bank_name;
```

**Output : B : Generating the flattened result**

```
(bofa)
(chase)
```

Any inputs on why we are not able to flatten the bag in alias C and D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you do not specify a schema for a `map`, it defaults to `bytearray`, as you can see in the [official documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#map-schema):

```
A = LOAD 'a.csv' AS (bank_details:map[]);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(bank_details#'banks') AS bank_name;
describe B;
B: {bank_name: bytearray}
```

Therefore, when you try to cast it to a `bag` it will result in a `ClassCastException` because `DataByteArray` cannot be cast to `DataBag`. If you perform a `dump` on `C` it will still work because you are not doing any real operation on the data, merely projecting it. However, once you call the `FLATTEN` function it will expect to receive a `DataBag`, and fail when trying to cast your `bytearray` to it.

The reason why it works in your second case is that you are correctly indicating the schema for the map, which is a `bag`, so it won't get the default value, which is `bytearray`:

```
A = LOAD 'a.csv' AS (bank_details:bag{t:(bank_name:chararray)});
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I didn't see that in the second case you are not using a `map`, you are using directly a `bag`. If you want to use a `map`, you can as long as you indicate the schema to avoid what mentioned above:

```
A = LOAD 'a.csv' AS (bank_details:map[{(name:chararray)}]);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(bank_details#'banks') AS bank_name;

dump B;
(bofa)
(chase)
```

Comment: Agreed on your thoughts, in my use case I have a map where the values are of different data types. Its not a map having all bag values. Any inputs on going for explicit casting like the way I am trying for alias C : C = FOREACH A GENERATE bank_details#'banks' AS banks: bag{t:(bank:chararray)};

Comment: @MuraliRao I'm not sure I understood what you meant there... You have a map with different types, right? You cannot do an explicit casting from a `bytearray` to a `bag`, both classes have nothing in common so you get an exception. The only way for you to solve this is by specifying a schema for your map. If the values might vary, can't you put them all in a bag? I mean, a map with bags inside: `A = LOAD 'a.csv' AS (bank_details:map[bag{t:(name:chararray)}]);`

Comment: Yes, I meant map having values of different data types. For eg. key1#2, key2#{(bofa),(chase)}. I understand that we wont be able to convert byte array to bag. Will try to have all key values as bag. Thanks for your inputs !